# How long does tortilla dough keep for?

Tags: dough, mexican-cuisine, tortilla, masa

I am making tortillas with masa harina corn flour [according to this recipe](http://www.simplyrecipes.com/recipes/how_to_make_corn_tortillas/).

Can I make it a few hours in advance and cook the tortillas just before they are to be eaten?

Or should I cook them after making the dough and then reheat them just before they are to be eaten?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's absolutely fine to make the dough in advance, just don't let it dry out. It even freezes well. There is more good information on [Serious Eats](http://www.seriouseats.com/recipes/2014/05/masa-dough-recipe.html) on the subject.

Keep it on the counter for up to a day, refrigerated for up to three days, frozen for up to 6 months (for best quality). In any case that you want to hold the dough, be sure that your baking powder (if using) is of the ["double acting"](http://whatscookingamerica.net/Q-A/BakingPowder.htm) variety.